# How to make a universal call to this method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, methods, firebase-authentication, call

how can I make a universal call to this method, I need to use it in another file but it is not possible for me. help me flutter

```
 void loginScreen() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return LoginScreen();
      },
    );
  }

  void registerScreen() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return RegisterScreen();
      },
    );
  }`enter code here`
```

I have this code, and I want to implement it here

```
class _ButtonTextState extends State<ButtonText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
        onPressed: () {
          loginScreen();//Error
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Ingresa aquí",
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12),
        ));
  }
```

This is the problem, I have a method that I need to reuse, but I can't get it out of the original file, I don't know how to import it or make the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a common class like `utils.dart`. And add your dialogs there.

**utils.dart**

```
class Utils {

  static void loginScreen({required BuildContext context}) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return LoginScreen();
      },
    );
  }

  static void registerScreen({required BuildContext context}) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return RegisterScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

//
Now, Import `utils.dart` class into `ButtonText` widget and use like this: `Utils.loginScreen(context: context);`
//

```
class _ButtonTextState extends State<ButtonText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
        onPressed: () {
          Utils.loginScreen(context: context);
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Ingresa aquí",
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12),
        ));
  }
```